Mobile Android App in Visual Studio 2022 produces 96 errors connected to Google Libraries
The problem is, that the whole project worked well with previous versions of VS 2022.
I still have a virtual machine, where it is compiling well.
But with a fresh installation of Visual Studio 2022 these errors occur, although the nuget packages are installed.
All in all 96 errors. I just copied a few of them.
Here are some of the errors.
error: package com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient does not exist com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks
error: package com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient does not exist com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
error: package com.google.android.gms.common does not exist public void onConnectionFailed (com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult p0) 
error: package com.google.android.gms.common does not exist private native void n_onConnectionFailed (com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult p0)
error: package com.google.android.gms.common.api does not exist com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback
error: package com.google.android.gms.common.api does not exist public void onResult (com.google.android.gms.common.api.Result p0) 
error: package com.google.android.gms.common.api does not exist private native void n_onResult (com.google.android.gms.common.api.Result p0)
error: package com.google.android.gms.common.api does not exist com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback 
error: package com.google.android.gms.common.api does not exist public void onResult (com.google.android.gms.common.api.Result p0) 
error: package com.google.android.gms.common.api does not exist private native void n_onResult (com.google.android.gms.common.api.Result p0)
error: package com.google.android.gms.tasks does not exist com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener
error: package com.google.android.gms.tasks does not exist public void onComplete (com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task p0) 
error: package com.google.android.gms.tasks does not exist private native void n_onComplete (com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task p0) 
error: package com.google.android.gms.location does not exist com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener
error: package com.google.firebase.iid does not exist extends com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService
error: cannot find symbolif (getClass () == MyFirebaseIIDService.class) {symbol:   method getClass()location: class MyFirebaseIIDService    
error: package com.google.firebase.messaging does not existextends com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService
error: cannot find symbolif (getClass () == MyFirebaseMessagingService.class) {symbol:   method getClass()location: class MyFirebaseMessagingService
error: package com.google.firebase.messaging does not existpublic void onMessageReceived (com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage p0)
error: package com.google.firebase.messaging does not existprivate native void n_onMessageReceived (com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage p0)
error: package com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient does not existcom.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
error: package com.google.android.gms.common does not existpublic void onConnectionFailed (com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult p0)
error: package com.google.android.gms.common does not existprivate native void n_onConnectionFailed (com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult p0)
error: package com.google.android.gms.common.images.ImageManager does not existcom.google.android.gms.common.images.ImageManager.OnImageLoadedListener
error: package com.google.android.gms.location does not existcom.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener
error: package com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap does not existcom.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener
error: package com.google.android.gms.maps.model does not existpublic void onCameraChange (com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition p0)
error: package com.google.android.gms.maps.model does not existprivate native void n_onCameraChange (com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition p0)
error: package com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap does not existcom.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener
error: package com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap does not existcom.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveCanceledListener
error: package com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap does not existcom.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveListener
error: package com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap does not existcom.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener
error: package com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap does not existcom.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnCircleClickListener
error: package com.google.android.gms.maps.model does not existpublic void onCircleClick (com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Circle p0)
error: package com.google.android.gms.maps.model does not exist
error: package com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap does not existcom.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnGroundOverlayClickListener
error: package com.google.android.gms.maps.model does not existpublic void onGroundOverlayClick (com.google.android.gms.maps.model.GroundOverlay p0)
error: package com.google.android.gms.maps.model does not existprivate native void n_onGroundOverlayClick (com.google.android.gms.maps.model.GroundOverlay p0)
error: package com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap does not existcom.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnIndoorStateChangeListener
error: package com.google.android.gms.maps.model does not existpublic void onIndoorLevelActivated (com.google.android.gms.maps.model.IndoorBuilding p0)
error: package com.google.android.gms.maps.model does not existprivate native void n_onIndoorLevelActivated (com.google.android.gms.maps.model.IndoorBuilding p0)
error: package com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap does not existcom.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener

I tried out almost everything I could think of.
